# Java program makes user enter same input twice to run after initial input error

Tags: java, while-loop

I am having problems with my program. Everything is running smoothly, however, when the user inputs the wrong variable it does display the right feedback, but the user then has to enter one extra variable than previously stated.

Maybe it's a simple mistake I have made, but I can't see it..

It's confusing. An example when I run the program:

```
How many grades would you like to average? 
3

Please enter 3 grades: 
90
jf //Intentional user input error
You've entered a non-numerical variable. Please enter a number: 
95
100 //The program should go ahead and calculate the average after this is entered
100 //It should not expect this fourth input if the amount of grades is 3

Your average is: 96.67
```

The second 100 input in the console should not appear, but it does when the user has at least one input error. If I were to run the program and input all the correct variables, then the program works smoothly.

This error also occurs when asking for how many grades the user would like to average. I thought it'd be easier to view what's wrong with my program by the second part.

I'm trying to get this program to run smoothly. Help is appreciated!

```
for (gradesCount = 0; gradesCount < gradeNumber; gradesCount++) {
            // Check if the input variables are numerical variables
            while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
                input.next();
                System.out.println("You've entered a non-numerical variable. Please enter a number: ");
                while (input.nextInt()<= 0){

                System.out.println("You've entered a negative number. Please eneter a positive number: ");
                }

            }
            // Read grade input
            gradesInput = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `input.hasNextDouble()` you can try below

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter total no of input ");
    int total = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    int[] input = new int[total];
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter number ");
                String in = scan.nextLine();
                input[i] = Integer.parseInt(in);
                break;
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                System.err.print("Invalid input. ");
            }
        }

    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
```

It'll force the user input only numbers, you can add boundaries or change data type if required.

Comment: Thank you for your input! However one of the purposes of my program is that it gives the user feedback on why there initial input was wrong. I just want to figure out why the user needs to enter the input twice after entering a wrong one..

Comment: check if `input[i] > 0` then print reason for not accepting the input, instead of `Invalid input. ` print `not a number`

Comment: From scanner you're taking `input.next()` and  `input.nextInt()`.you'd get either `input.nextInt()` or `input.next()`